# Action is executing twice on performClick(nil)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift5

I have the problem that my onClick actions are always executed 2 times. I have the following code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.pressStartbutton),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Startbutton"),
        object: nil)
}

@objc private func pressStartbutton(notification: NSNotification){
    start_button.isEnabled=true
    start_button.performClick(nil)
}
```

Each time the "pressStartbutton" function is executed, the action always runs 2 times in a row. How should the code look so that it executes it only once?

Comment: Is the notification sent 2 times? Is `awakeFromNib` called 2 times?

Comment: Good question. From another Class I call this only one Time. Don't know why awakefromnib is executed twice.

Comment: `awakeFromNib()` can be called multiple times, for example if the view contains a table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the Problem. I put the NotificationCenter Part into "viewDidLoad" instead of "awakeFromNib". Now the function is executed once.